# 360 Virtual Tour setup: compact VS full setup?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, panorama, 360-panorama

I have 2 camera bodies:

- Nikon D610
- Sony NEX-5R

I have these lenses (which I can fit on both cameras with a NEX adapter):

- Opteka (Rokinon/Samyang) 6.5mm f3.5 Fisheye
- Sigma 12-24 (Mark I)

I would like to make Interior 360 Virtual Tours. I have not bought a panoramic head yet.

Question:

- Should I get a compact pano head (i.e. Nodal Ninja 3) and use the NEX 5R; Travel light, smaller footprint, easier to "maneuver." Or,
- Should I get a full-sized pano head (i.e. Nodal Ninja 4) and be able to use my full-frame camera with superior image quality OR my smaller camera too; Bulkier, more expensive.

Comment: Take a look on automated panoheads. The price is not that high, but the added value is. http://gigapan.com/cms/shop/store

Answer (score 1):

I think you pretty much answered your own question--which is more important to you--image quality or traveling light? The difference probably isn't as big as you're thinking, since the NNs break down into pretty small packages, all told. I tend to keep my NN3 disassembled with the horizontal and vertical arm assemblies separate, so you're packing two bars, vs. an L-plate.

I would also state that I use a Nodal Ninja 3 with either my 5DMkII+Sigma 8/3.5 circular fisheye or my micro four-thirds GX-7 + Rokinon 7.5mm f/3.5 fisheye, and have no trouble with either, so getting a full-frame diagonal fisheye (say, a 15/2.8) might be an alternative to using the 12-24 and still sticking with the smaller head, but still having higher quality than the 7.5 will get you on APS-C (although, gotta say. It's no optical slouch--better performer, overall, for me than my Sigma 8/3.5 when used on APS-c).

But. With your NEX+mft Samyang/Rokinon 7.5/3.5 fisheye + adapter (if the fisheye lens's hood is shaved) is actually a popular combination among equirectangular shooters, because, like my 5DII+Sigma 8mm, you get 180° HFoV, and it *can* be handheld and only requires 4 shots around at 90-degree intervals to cover the entire sphere.  A simple [plumbline](http://panotool.com/panotool/pages/strings.html) might be all that you need with that combo.

Obviously, however, if you swap to an ultrawide rectilinear lens, you're going to need more precise rotation and a lot more shots to cover the scene, and a panohead and tripod are more likely.  And you're liable to be able to use the NN4 with both setups.